# I don't understand how to spawn multiple platforms in pygame in the game FallDown

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently started to develop a game called falldown and have completed making the controls, start screen, and the ball but I am struggling in randomly spawning the platforms. I had been able to temporarily draw a random platform, but in order to give the illusion that the specific platform was moving up, I needed to draw the same platform again and I couldn't figure out how to do that.

I researched a lot and found these two code samples:
https://github.com/Beavotropper2/FallDown
https://sourceforge.net/projects/falldown/
but I couldn't really understand how they solved this issue. Can you help me understand how to possibly create the multiple platforms generated that move up like in falldown?

Answer (score 2):

I'd implement the platforms as follows: The `Platform` class only needs to contain an image (`pygame.Surface`) and a `pygame.Rect` which is used to store the position (can also be utilized for collision detection).

In the `update` method I only change the `self.rect.y` position to move the sprite and delete it when it's above the top of the screen.

To store the platform sprites, I use a `pygame.sprite.Group` which allows me to update and blit all contained sprites with two method calls.

The sprites get added to the group separately in the `add_platforms` function, where I first call `random.randint` to get the number of platforms and then pass it and the `range(0, 800, 100)` to [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to get 4-7 random x-coords. Then you can just loop over this list and pass the coords to the sprite instances.

I use the [`pygame.time.set_timer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) function to generate a custom event (`ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT`) every two seconds, which you can handle in the event loop to call the `add_platforms` function.

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
PLATFORM_IMAGE = pygame.Surface((100, 20))
PLATFORM_IMAGE.fill((30, 220, 150))
# This event is needed for the timer and to add platforms.
ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT+1


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, platform_image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = platform_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 1

        if self.rect.y < -50:
            self.kill()


def add_platforms(group):
    """Add platforms to a sprite group.

    Choose 4-7 random x-positions, create the Platform sprites (pass
    the x- and y-positions) and add them to the passed group.
    """
    platform_count = random.randint(4, 7)
    positions = random.sample(range(0, 800, 100), platform_count)
    y = game_display.get_height()
    for x in positions:
        group.add(Platform(x, y, PLATFORM_IMAGE))


def main_game():
    # This will add a `ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT` to the event queue after two seconds.
    pygame.time.set_timer(ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT, 2000)
    platform_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    add_platforms(platform_group)

    game_exit = False

    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            # Call the `add_platforms` function if
            # an `ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT` occurs.
            elif event.type == ADD_PLATFORM_EVENT:
                add_platforms(platform_group)

        # Call the update methods of all contained sprites.
        platform_group.update()

        game_display.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Blit the images of all sprites at their rects.
        platform_group.draw(game_display)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

main_game()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: One more note: If you want to move the platforms by a floating point number, you need to give the sprites an additional `self.y_position` attribute to which you add the speed each frame, e.g. `self.y_position += 0.5`, and then assign the position to the rect `self.rect.y = self.y_position`. You have to do it in this way, because pygame.Rect attributes can only be ints and floats are truncated.